# Multiple definition of linking error in C

Tags: c, linker

I am developing an application in C. I want to use a local function with the same name in more than one source files. Let me simplify the issue:

In hell.c

```
void myLocalFunc(){ printf("Hello hell\r\n"); }
```

In world.c

```
void myLocalFunc(){ printf("Hello world\r\n"); }
```

Because they are local functions only, i dont declare them in header files. But when i compile the project, it gives me "Multiple definition of 'myLocalFunc'" error message and also this one: "Multiple definition of 'myLocalFunc' (first defined here)".

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace it with

```
static void myLocalFunc(){ printf("Hello world\r\n"); }
```

Or, if you're using C++, you can also use an anonymous namespace like this:

```
namespace {
void myLocalFunc(){ printf("Hello world\r\n"); }
}
```

Comment: That is the correct answer and a real urgent help. Thank you.

Comment: Why exactly does this work and where's the problem coming from?